# How to pass empty value in python variable or any other way to do

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy

I'm trying to convert excel formula into python script, but at one point I'm struggling. There is a cell in excel which doesn't have any value, the cell is empty though, since this cell actually does not require to enter any value and sometime does, so based on the empty cell it produce different value, and if I enter any value in that cell it produce different value. So I'm trying same thing in python to pass empty value and get desired output. This is variable which I tried but not working for me :-

```
varpbmt = Decimal(input('Enter pbmt')).quantize(Decimal('.01'), rounding = ROUND_HALF_EVEN)
```

The error what I'm getting is as given below -

```
Enter FlagE-406A | T1

Enter unique idE-406A | T1

Enter mt1.41

Enter pbmt <------     **[here I'm pressing enter from keyboard expecting it passing empty]**

Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "C:\E-RBI\Testing Pyrhon\5_1_loss.py", line 65, in <module>
    print(fiftyeoneloss())

  File "C:\E-RBI\Testing Pyrhon\5_1_loss.py", line 16, in fiftyeoneloss
    PrevBaselineMeasuredThickness = Decimal(input('Enter pbmt')).quantize(Decimal('.01'), rounding = ROUND_HALF_EVEN)

InvalidOperation: [<class 'decimal.ConversionSyntax'>]
```

Comment: Could you paste the error here please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What exactly should varpbmt be if the user does not input anything?

```
varpbmt = Decimal(input('Enter pbmt') or 0.0).quantize(Decimal('.01'), rounding = ROUND_HALF_EVEN)
```

Otherwise you could use **"or"** to define a default value if the user does not enter anything.

In case you want to catch an empty string and do a different operation:

```
ipt = input('Enter pbmt')
if ipt:
    varpbmt = Decimal(ipt).quantize(Decimal('.01'), rounding = ROUND_HALF_EVEN)
else:  # Case someone just hits ENTER
    DO SOMETHING COMPLETLY DIFFERENT HERE
```

Comment: since 0.0 produce different value not according to empty

Comment: You get the error because Decimal can not convert an empty string to a decimal, therefore you have to define the behavior for this case either by providing a default value for the input statement or catching an empty string and then do something different than the Decimal statement.

Comment: sorry bro I undone your accepted answer, since excel formula is so complex I got confused on that time, however can you guide how can I catch empty string ? or can you come on hangout i will show you the exact scenario [may be I'm lacking in words to explain the scenario]

Comment: I edited my answer with code to catch an empty string.